# Arquillian searches maven dependencies in wrong paths at startup (real existing files but in wrong folder locations)

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

I'm working to implement Integration Tests for my project using Arquillian.
Here are the dependencies that I use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

At startup, it seems to be searching for the maven dependencies in totally messed-up path locations.

Below are a few examples:

```
2020-04-01 14:37:17 WARNING org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/***/.m2/repository/com/github/junrar/junrar/0.7/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\com\github\junrar\junrar\0.7\commons-vfs2-2.0.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

The "commons-vfs2-2.0.jar" file **does** exist, but in a different folder location: *.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-vfs2\2.0*

```
2020-04-01 14:37:17 WARNING org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/apache/sis/core/sis-referencing/0.6/jsr-275-0.9.3.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\apache\sis\core\sis-referencing\0.6\jsr-275-0.9.3.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Similarly, the "jsr-275-0.9.3.jar" file **does** exist, but in a different folder location: *.m2\repository\javax\measure\jsr-275\0.9.3*.

And I have ***hundreds*** of such WARNINGs.

Anybody knows what can be the cause for this ?

Thanks.